# Using NATS Queuing in a Request/Reply Manner

Tags: go, message-queue

Using [NATS.IO](http://nats.io/) message queue; Is it OK to send messages in a request/reply manner (using `nc.Request(...)`) but subscribe in a queue manner (using `nc.QueueSubscribe(...)` and reply from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is by design and allows you to easily scale the group of receivers.